# Facebook Open Graph post where description references different object

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to recreate an Open Graph post that looks like this:

[image]

As far as I can tell, the action is "flipped a story" and the object is "cool shit."

I'm not clear how Facebook pulled in the title and the description for the actual story though.

If you view source on the [object url](http://flip.it/MkuRo), the og metatags have no reference to the story, but just the magazine "cool shit".

Ultimately I want my post to be structured like so:

```
Joe Smith saved a travel highlight into List1 on AppName.

 {travel highlight image}   {travel highlight title}
                            {travel highlight description}
```

Comment: Have you checked https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/

Comment: Yeah, definitely. Unfortunately they only describe the simple scenario of "person did something to object."  I'll need to do just that (which I know how to do) but then have the image, description and title reference a different object. Look at clipboards meta tags though, and they make no reference of this other object.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how post something;

[post wall](http://blue-and-orange.net/articles/facebook/posting-to-user%27s-facebook-wall-in-aspnet-mvc-4/)

for image you must add;

postValues.Add("picture", "...../myimage.jpg");

for title;

postValues.Add("name", "travel highlight title");

for description;

```
postValues.Add("description", "travel highlight description");
```

and u can add

```
   postValues.Add("link", "....");
   postValues.Add("caption", "....");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need this to be an Open Graph post, not just a regular post to someone's wall.